# if and & statement in R

Tags: r

I have a data.frame with 4 columns like that:

```
> bb
               V1      V2      V3       V4
1         ARFGEF2 ARFGEF2 ARFGEF2     <NA>
2           SFRS5    <NA>   SRSF5     <NA>
3 ENSG00000215104    <NA>    <NA> CHMP1B2P
4            EDF1    EDF1    EDF1     <NA>
5    LOC100133678    <NA>    <NA>     <NA>
6            CD3G    CD3G       -     <NA>
7           GNAI2   GNAI2   GNAI2     <NA>
```

I want to create a new column according to values on columns 2, 3, and 4. What I was trying to do is :
If `bb[,2]` is a `NA` *AND* `bb[,3]` has a value then `bb[,5]` would be the value of `bb[,3]`, if `bb[,2]` is a `NA` *AND* `bb[,3]` is a `NA` and `df[,4]` has a value then `bb[,5]` would be the value of `bb[,4]`, else `bb[,5]` would be `df[,1]`. Here is the expected output:

```
> bb
                V1      V2      V3       V4       V5
1          ARFGEF2 ARFGEF2 ARFGEF2     <NA>  ARFGEF2
2            SFRS5    <NA>   SRSF5     <NA>    SRSF5
3  ENSG00000215104    <NA>    <NA> CHMP1B2P CHMP1B2P
4             EDF1    EDF1    EDF1     <NA>     EDF1
5     LOC100133678    <NA>    <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
6             CD3G    CD3G       -     <NA>        -
7            GNAI2   GNAI2   GNAI2     <NA>    GNAI2
```

I've trying this code but it doesn't work:

```
> for (i in 1:nrow(bb)){
      if (is.na(bb[i,2] & !(is.na(bb[i,3])))) {bb[i,5] <- as.character(bb[i,3])}
    else if (is.na(bb[i,2]) & !(is.na(bb[i,4]))) {bb[i,5] <- as.character(bb[i,4])}
    else { bb[i,5] <- bb[i,1]}
}
Warning messages:
 1: In Ops.factor(bb[i, 2], !(is.na(bb[i, 3]))) :
  & not meaningful for factors
 2: In Ops.factor(bb[i, 2], !(is.na(bb[i, 3]))) :
  & not meaningful for factors
 3: In Ops.factor(bb[i, 2], !(is.na(bb[i, 3]))) :
  & not meaningful for factors
 4: In Ops.factor(bb[i, 2], !(is.na(bb[i, 3]))) :
  & not meaningful for factors
 5: In Ops.factor(bb[i, 2], !(is.na(bb[i, 3]))) :
  & not meaningful for factors
 6: In Ops.factor(bb[i, 2], !(is.na(bb[i, 3]))) :
  & not meaningful for factors
 7: In Ops.factor(bb[i, 2], !(is.na(bb[i, 3]))) :
  & not meaningful for factors
```

How could I use `&` with the `if` statement? This is an example of a much longer data.frame where I would like to create a new column (`V5`) taking the values of `V1` if `V2` is not a `NA`. In case of `V2` being a `NA`, first I want to check whether `V3` has a value and if it is `TRUE` then `V5` would be `V3` value, second, if `V3` is a `NA` and `V4` has a value then `V5` would be the value of `V4`, finally if `V3` and `V4` are `NA` then `V5` would be `V1`.

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `for` loop should be using `&&` instead of `&`. Also a missing bracket at the first `is.na`. But try the `ifelse` function, something along the lines

```
bb[,5] <- ifelse(is.na(bb[,2]) & !is.na(bb[,3]), 
            bb[,3], 
            ifelse(is.na(bb[,2]) & !is.na(bb[,4]), bb[,4], bb[,1])
          )
```

(untested)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Karsten W, it worked perfectly I didn't know about nested ifelse :-)

Comment: That does not answer his question 'How could I use `&` with the if statement'. If you use `&` in your `if` statement it means it is vectorized (thus it can return a vector of booleans) whilst using `&&` it will return only one `true` or `false` value.